# Download attribute is not working in html

Tags: html, download

Download attribute in  tag is not working at all. I've tried everything that I can do but still I am not able to do it. I just simply want to make a download button.
You can see my code which is written below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>
        test
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a target="_blank" href="img1.jpg" download>Click to Download</a>   
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where I am wrong. really appreciate your help. and If I am asking previously asked question please give me the link of it also.

Comment: You might not need the target attribute. Also try changing the href attribute to src.

Comment: see it is anchor tag and anchor tag don't have any src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the download to work,
you have to specify the path to the image you want the user to download.
If the item cannot be found the download will not work.

```
<a target="_blank" href="./images/img1.jpg" download>Click to Download</a>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>
        test
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" download>Click to Download</a>   
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that href="img1.jpg" is the path of the file that i want to download. it is in current folder where my html file sits. the problem is instead of downloading it it is just opening it.

Comment: this does literally not work for me in any browser